# Print Index of a multilist

Tags: c++, loops, indexing, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to print the index of a multi linked list. Each node has two elements- a warehouse number and a tool number. I am printing all the tools in each warehouse. I am having a problem with iterating correctly through the list.

I am not getting the correct values and am having trouble finding the problem in my method.

```
struct Node
{
    int WarehouseNumber;
    int ToolNumber;
    struct Node *n;
}

void showWarehouses()
{
    int tempvalue;
    bool flag = false;
    struct Node *s;
    s = start;
    if (start == NULL)  
    {
        cout<<"Unable";
        return;
    }
    s->WarehouseN = tempvalue;
    cout<<"Warehouse "<<tempvalue<< ": Tool ";
    while(s != NULL)
        {
            if (s->WarehouseN == tempvalue)
            {
            flag = true;
            cout<< s->ToolN <<" ";
            s = s->next;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is there. I will post my actual output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned any values to `tempvalue` so it causes undefined behavior. Read [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c)

Also based on what you have in `struct Node` and your code, I think you can have something like this picture in the program and you want to print them.

[image: Lined List]

So to top it off I would write something like this code:

```
void showWarehouses()
{
    int tempvalue=1;
    bool flag, cont;
    struct Node *s;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Unable";
        return;
    }

    cont = true;
    while (cont)
    {
        cont = false, flag = false;
        s = start;
        while (s)
        {
            if (s->WarehouseN == tempvalue){
                cont = true;
                if (!flag){
                    cout << "Warehouse " << tempvalue << ": Tool ";
                    flag = true;
                }
                cout << s->ToolN << " ";
            }
            s = s->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
        tempvalue++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I populate the value by iterating through the linked list?

Comment: Yes, also add the code for `struct Node` so I could help more with printing `Tool`.

Comment: Okay I will post the struct

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming that ->warehouseN and ->toolN get the warehouse and tool nums accordingly. This is for right after your if statement.

```
struct Node *temp;
while (s != NULL){
    temp = s;
    cout << "Warehouse " << s->warehouseN << ": Tool ";
    while (s!= NULL) {
        cout << s->toolN << " ";
        s = s-> next;
    }
    s = temp->next;
    cout << endl;
}
```

also, you should probably initiate s **before** setting it as start

Comment: I want to search the whole list for the same warehouse number and print all tools associated with that warehouse, consecutively. The code above would print everything separate.

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
s = start;
struct Node *s;
```

compiles, you have an `s` in a wider scope that just got set to start before being hidden inside `showWarehouses` by another variable named `s`. That would be a bad thing.

Anyway, The immediate result is `showWarehouses`'s `s` is never initialized and it's probably dumb unluck that the program doesn't crash. Since `s` is not initialized, the rest of the program is printing garbage so the output being wrong is to be expected.